# Zero-free region for the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am studying de la Vallee Poussin's proof of the zero-free region of the Riemann zeta function. Assuming the following bound

$$\Re \frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s/2) \leq \log \vert s/2\vert + \min \Big(\frac{\pi/2}{\Im s}, \frac{1}{\Re s}\Big),$$ what is the best constant $C$ that can be obtained in the zero-free region

$$\Re s > 1 - \frac{1}{C\log \vert \Im s \vert}, \quad\vert \Im s\vert > 2\,? $$

So, basically, I am trying to make the proof given by Poussin explicit.
The main place where I am stumped is how do I use the above bound, though I can see how the bound follows from the Stirling's asymptotic formula for Gamma.
Any ideas and/or hints?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: For your information, the first nontrivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ is at $s=\frac12+i\gamma$ with $\gamma\approx14.2$.

Comment: This is a topic of active research; you'll want to search for "*explicit* zero-free region for the zeta function".

Comment: I think Kevin Ford has made some recent progress on this. Search for his work and the references contained in it.